# Validating newly created inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using small attachment form with dynamically created inputs.

These new inputs are created this way:

```
function addAttachmentRow() {
    var htmlRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="file_name[]"></td></tr>';
    $("#attachment_list").append(htmlRow);
}
```

and I am trying to prepare validating function, but this code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input[name^="file_name"]').each(function() {
        $(this).keydown(function(){ 
            if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#FFCCCC");
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid #665252");
                $(this).css("color", "#B20000");
            } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#F5FFEB");
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid #5CE65C");
                $(this).css("color", "#145214");
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

but it only applies to the very first element which is created statically. It does not effect elements, created when "addAttachmentRow" is clicked and new input added.

Changing it to

```
$('input[name^="file_name[]"]').each(function() {
```

doesn't help either, and I just need to have [] in input's name.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls use classes as opposed to inline styles!

Comment: Try to use `.on` instead of `.each` with the following changes:
`.on( 'keydown', fn )` and replace the `fn` with your current `.each` parameter and remove the line `$(this).keydown(function(){` and it's ending brace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It happens. It doesn't select the element with that code. You will need to use $(document).on method instead of this.

**Solution**:

Use this code

```
$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {
    // code
});
```

e.g.

```
$(document).on('each', 'input[name^="file_name[]"]', function() {
    alert('Event fired!');
});
```

Comment: `each` isn't a valid event.  You could use `keydown` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind event with the document for dynamic elements:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('keydown', 'input[name^="file_name"]', function(e) {
    /* to do here */
  });
});
```

Try this demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('keydown', 'input[name^="file_name"]', function(e) {
    var err = 2 > $.trim(this.value).length;
    $(this).toggleClass('rest', !err).toggleClass('err', err);
  });
});

function addAttachmentRow() {
  var htmlRow = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="file_name[]"></td></tr>';
  $("#attachment_list").append(htmlRow);
}
```

```css
.rest {
  background-color: #F5FFEB;
  border: 1px solid #5CE65C;
  color: #145214;
}
.err {
  background-color: #FFCCCC;
  border: 1px solid #665252;
  color: #B20000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addAttachmentRow()' />
<table id='attachment_list'>
</table>
```